# Is there any way to dismiss Nightmare after summoning him?

Tags: devil-may-cry-5

With the character V you can summon Nightmare which then begins to deplete your devil gauge.

After summoning him, is there are way to dismiss him so that he doesnt consume all the devil gauge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dismiss Nightmare by using the same button you used to summon him (on PS4 this is the L1 bumper). Note it does not work right away, you need to wait for him to completely materialize before you dismiss him.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try when I get the chance. I thought I had tried this and it didn't work, but I will try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss Nightmare using the same button, but it looks like sometimes it requires longer hold to actually do action. By default it set up on left shoulder button (L1 on ps4, LS on xbox, LB on steam controllers and so on). Didn't tried to play with keyboard, so don't know if it's a controller related issue or some kind of devil trigger bug.